# Linguistic signs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap template for my web site but i have problem with linguistic signs in menu.
In text on website everything is ok but on menu bar font not show linguistic signs. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Font have polish linguistic signs. It shows liguistic signs but they are from other font.

CSS with font useage:

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;

    font-weight: 300; 
    font-style: normal; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* Fix for webkit rendering */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with a code sample? How are your special characters encoded in your code?

Comment: Do you know how to inspect an element?? if so it will show exactly were those fonts are comming from.

Comment: I've imported font from google fonts and its just wrote as text on html like USŁUGI or something

Comment: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: Can you place the CSS that you use to apply the font into your question.

Comment: Are you sure the Roboto font contains those letters? And are you sure the CSS you're showing does get applied? I see that the background color of your screenshot is not #ffffff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, many Google fonts contain only Latin 1 characters, which more or less means characters used in Western European languages. For Polish, for example, you need to use a version of the font that contains additional letters. If you use the default version of Roboto, the additional letters will be displayed using some other font in the system (in this case, the browser’s default sans-serif font).

When using a font as hosted by Google, the Google pages such as the [Roboto selection page](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto) contain item 2, “Choose the character sets you want”. Check the boxes that apply; in this case, check “Latin Extended (latin-ext)”. Google then shows you the element you need to use:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

To be exact, the ampersand “&” should be escaped, as required by general HTML rules:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: It look like after refreshing the website it is working but after maybe 2 seconds it's change linguistic signs to sans-serif

Comment: @KorWojci, you need to show the exact code you are using – something that lets other reconstruct the problem and analyze it.